# $11c+2d=86$ has no solution.

Tags: number-theory, proof-verification, linear-diophantine-equations

> Show that, in the year $1996$, no one could claim on his birthday, that his age was 
>   the sum of the digits of the year, in which, he was born.

My attempt:-
 Suppose a person born in the year $19\bar{cd}$ claims that his age ,in $1996$ , is equal to the sum of the digits of $19\bar{cd}$. This implies that $$1996-19\bar{cd}=1+9+c+d$$
Therefore, We can write $$96-\bar{cd}=10+c+d$$ 
This implies that $$96-10c-d=10+c+d$$
Which reduces to  $$11c+2d=86$$ It is easily checked that no $c,d$ satisfying $0 \le c,d\le9$ satisfy the above linear diophantine equation. Hence the result. Does this look correct?(I think ,not) .

P.S. We do not consider the years $18..$ ,$17..$ etc. As the largest sum(of digits) possible for any four digit number is 36...

Comment: Hint: all integers are congruent to the sum of their digits modulo $9$.

Comment: Why don't you think it's right?  It looks good to me.

Comment: Hello Connor , I don't see how that helps.

Comment: You answer is correct. $c$ has to be even and $0\leq 86-11c=2d\leq 18,$ so $68\leq 11c\leq 86$ so  $6<c<8.$

Answer (score 1):

Using trial and error , one can find that (0,43) are the solutions of the given diophantine equation.

Hence the general values of  x and y are:

$$C = 2t $$

$$D = 43-11t$$

for positive values of x and y :
$$t< 4$$

and the possible pairs of positive c and d are $(2,32),(4,21)$ and $(6,10).$

But Since c,d < 10 (They Are Digits), There Is no possible solution.